# safari 5 resize flash application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, browser, safari

Just notice that after updating to Safari 5 (mac) all the flash applications that respond to resize events got sluggish.

try:
http://www.tutorio.com/media/flash/liquid-demo.html

this works great with firefox 3.6.3, Chrome can deal with it fine, although not so fast as Firefox, but new Safari gives a awful experience, distorting all content if you do fast resizing.

Any ideas why is this happening / and how can I get a better performance with safari browsers?

Comment: Maybe it's a new "feature" Apple added given their love of flash...

Comment: Just tried your link (as well as some of my own full-browser flash sites) in Safari 5 in 64 bit on Snow Leopard w/ Flash 10  and they all work perfectly.

Comment: i'm on a imac 3.06GHz intelCoreDuo 4GB, running Safari 5.0 (6533.16) and flash player 10.1. I've tried both versions of flash normal and debug. Both give me a delay in the flash elements when resizing the window, as they where animated to go to theirs final position. I'll try to post a video... before I'll try different machines.
Thanks for the testing :)

Comment: just tryed on a different machine, same specs and it works ok. Can't figure out what this can be.

Comment: ok, found the problem. Thanks Mark L for the hint :) I was running safari in 32 bits mode.

Comment: will someone answer this so I can mark a correct answer :P ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari may be running in 32 bit mode. Get Info and toggle the checkbox to run in 64.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody told me this wouldn't happen in the Safari 5 on his computer. So at least there might be a chance to turn the damned feature off. (freaks me out)